# Is there a formula that swaps two elements in an array?

Tags: dart

Is there a formula that swaps two elements in an array?

for example

```
nums=['a','b','c','d'];
```

Swapping d and b and making my new string

```
nums=['a','d','c','b'];
```

Since I will apply this process for all the elements in the array, it must be a general system.

Comment: Looks like there is this implementation: `https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/ListExtensions/swap.html`

Comment: is there any way to solve this without a package? because I am trying to solve lead code questions only using dart.

Comment: I updated my answer with how you can define this extension method yourself.

Comment: Can you include your code in order for us to see what you have tried? It will make our job a lot easier to point out where your mistake is. If you haven't tried anything, that goes against Stack Overflow rules of what constitutes a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`collection`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/ListExtensions/swap.html) package seems to include a `swap` method:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
    var nums=['a','b','c','d'];
    print(nums);
    nums.swap(1,3);
    print(nums);
}
```

Prints:

```
[a, b, c, d]
[a, d, c, b]
```

Install: https://pub.dev/packages/collection/install

`dart pub add collection`

`flutter pub add collection`

---

If you dont want the package import, the link actually includes the implementation, which you can reuse to define your own extension method:

```
extension Swappable on List {
  void swap(int a, int b) {
    var tmp = this[a];
    this[a] = this[b];
    this[b] = tmp;    
  }
}
```

Now you can run the same code without the package import.